# Apply array to underscore _.range

Tags: javascript, arrays, range, underscore.js

What is the simplest way to use underscore `_.range()` when the two values I want a range between are contained in an array?

```
var arr = [4,6];
var rng = _.range(arr, 1);  //throws error
```

Is there anything simpler `var rng = _.range(arr[0], arr[1] + 1, 1)`?

I don't know how to make `_.range.apply(null, arr)` give me a range that includes the `to` parameter.

Or is there an easier way to do this without underscore?

Comment: `var rng = _.range(arr[0], arr[1] + 1, 1)` seems to be the most reasonable solution. I mean, you could do `_.range.apply(null, arr).concat(arr[1] + 1)` but that isn't really any better, is it?

Comment: i would even avoid using arr[1].... `_.range.call(this, arr[0], arr[arr.length - 1]  + 1, 1)`

Comment: @FelixKling Okay, seems reasonable in comparison. Can you please explain what is happening with the chained `concat()`? Thanks.

Comment: I let MDN explain it: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat

Comment: Ah, easy enough. Thanks very much!